# Is it possible to update a variable for each row in select

Tags: sql, sql-server

In MySQL it can be easily done like

```
set @var= (select value from my_sequence);

insert into new_table (id, name)
select @var := @var + 1, name from old_table;
```

But I cannot find a way to do the same thing in SQL Server. Is it possible?
What are the alternatives?

Comment: Are you missing the point here? Why not just get a count of inserted records? why not just get the max sequence number? I don't understand what ou are trying to achieve here with that variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
DECLARE @Var int = (SELECT [value] FROM dbo.my_sequence WITH (UPDLOCK)); 
--Ensure the row can't be used while we're doing it, as I assume that
--the value would be updated later with the new sequence value

INSERT INTO dbo.new_table (id, name)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {Column to Order By}) + @Var,
       [name]
FROM dbo.old_table;
```

You could even achieve this without a variable:

```sql
INSERT INTO dbo.new_table (id, name)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {Column to Order By}) + ms.[value],
       ot.[name]
FROM dbo.old_table ot
     CROSS JOIN dbo.my_sequence ms WITH (UPDLOCK);
```

As a side note, syntax `SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM` is a [documented antipattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#c-antipattern-use-of-recursive-variable-assignment) in SQL Server and should be avoided.

Comment: There's no guarantee that I need to start with 1, may be it is a bigger number, as it should be a current sequence value.

Comment: So you want the value of `@var` + another number not the `+1` you have hard coded? Then pass the other value as a parameter too. In Pseudo SQL: `ROW_NUMBER() + Sequence + OtherNumber`

Comment: No, I want it to increment by 1 but the initial value may be anything, it depends on what value is in my_sequence table now.

Comment: Which it's using, @Bobby , so I don't understand your point. It's doing `ROW_NUMBER() + Sequence`